# How to break direct speech into two parts right?

Tags: speech

This is what I'm writing:

> "Let's go," she says, "before it's too late."

Should I do this instead ("B" is capital):

> "Let's go," she says, "Before it's too late."

Which one is right?

Comment: Why? Neither you nor the person being quoted is starting a new sentence.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: As long as you're asking a question, you might as well do so correctly. Your tile should be "How to break direct speech into two parts correctly?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From ODO - [Punctuation in direct speech](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/punctuation-in-direct-speech) (numbering added for ease of reference):

> If the direct speech is broken up by information about who is speaking, you need a comma (or a question mark or exclamation mark) to end the first piece of speech and a full stop or another comma before the second piece (before the inverted comma or commas):
>
> 1. ‘You’re right,’ he said. ‘It feels strange.’
> 2. ‘Thinking back,’ she said, ‘he didn’t expect to win.’
> 3. ‘No!’ he cried. ‘You can’t leave now!’

Your example has the same form as example 2 in the quote, so don't capitalise the continuation - leave it in lowercase.